# Wrong configuration in htaccess redirects from subfolder to main domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I got website on subfolder https://lofty-tibiabot.com/new/

and when I want go to https://lofty-tibiabot.com/new/wp-admin

I have noticed when I put https://lofty-tibiabot.com/new/wp-admin/index.php it works correctly

it redirects me to https://lofty-tibiabot.com/wp-admin

what i have to do with that?

---

here is htaccess from https://lofty-tibiabot.com

```
Options -MultiViews +FollowSymlinks -Indexes

#
# If mod_security is enabled, attempt to disable it.
# - Note, this will work on the majority of hosts but on
#   MediaTemple, it is known to cause random Internal Server
#   errors. For MediaTemple, please remove the block below
#
<IfModule mod_security.c>
  # Turn off mod_security filtering.
  SecFilterEngine Off

  # The below probably isn't needed, but better safe than sorry.
  SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>


 RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /


#
# MyBB "search engine friendly" URL rewrites
# - Note, for these to work with MyBB please make sure you have
#   the setting enabled in the Admin CP and you have this file
#   named .htaccess
#
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteRule ^([^&]*)&(.*)$ https://lofty-tibiabot.com/$1?$2 [L,QSA,R=301]

  #RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  #RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(.*)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]



  RewriteRule ^forum-([0-9]+)\.html$ forumdisplay.php?fid=$1 [L,QSA]
  RewriteRule ^forum-([0-9]+)-page-([0-9]+)\.html$ forumdisplay.php?fid=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]

  RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1 [L,QSA]
  RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-page-([0-9]+)\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
  RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-lastpost\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&action=lastpost [L,QSA]
  RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-nextnewest\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&action=nextnewest [L,QSA]
  RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-nextoldest\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&action=nextoldest [L,QSA]
  RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-newpost\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&action=newpost [L,QSA]
  RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-post-([0-9]+)\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&pid=$2 [L,QSA]

  RewriteRule ^post-([0-9]+)\.html$ showthread.php?pid=$1 [L,QSA]

  RewriteRule ^announcement-([0-9]+)\.html$ announcements.php?aid=$1 [L,QSA]

  RewriteRule ^user-([0-9]+)\.html$ member.php?action=profile&uid=$1 [L,QSA]

  RewriteRule ^calendar-([0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?calendar=$1 [L,QSA]
  RewriteRule ^calendar-([0-9]+)-year-([0-9]+)-month-([0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?calendar=$1&year=$2&month=$3 [L,QSA]
  RewriteRule ^calendar-([0-9]+)-year-([0-9]+)-month-([0-9]+)-day-([0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?action=dayview&calendar=$1&year=$2&month=$3&day=$4 [L,QSA]
  RewriteRule ^calendar-([0-9]+)-week-(n?[0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?action=weekview&calendar=$1&week=$2 [L,QSA]

  RewriteRule ^event-([0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?action=event&eid=$1 [L,QSA]


  # Google SEO workaround for search.php highlights:
# Make this rule the first rewrite rule in your .htaccess!
RewriteRule ^([^&]*)&(.*)$ https://lofty-tibiabot.com/$1?$2 [L,QSA,R=301]

# Google SEO 404:
ErrorDocument 404 /misc.php?google_seo_error=404

# Google SEO Sitemap:
RewriteRule ^sitemap\-([^./]+)\.xml$ misc.php?google_seo_sitemap=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# Google SEO URL Forums:
RewriteRule ^Forum\-([^./]+)$ forumdisplay.php?google_seo_forum=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# Google SEO URL Threads:
RewriteRule ^Thread\-([^./]+)$ showthread.php?google_seo_thread=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# Google SEO URL Announcements:
RewriteRule ^Announcement\-([^./]+)$ announcements.php?google_seo_announcement=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# Google SEO URL Users:
RewriteRule ^User\-([^./]+)$ member.php?action=profile&google_seo_user=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# Google SEO URL Calendars:
RewriteRule ^Calendar\-([^./]+)$ calendar.php?google_seo_calendar=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# Google SEO URL Events:
RewriteRule ^Event\-([^./]+)$ calendar.php?action=event&google_seo_event=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# Google SEO workaround for search.php highlights:
# Make this rule the first rewrite rule in your .htaccess!
RewriteRule ^([^&]*)&(.*)$ https://lofty-tibiabot.com/$1?$2 [L,QSA,R=301]

  <IfModule mod_env.c>
    SetEnv SEO_SUPPORT 1
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>

#
# If Apache is compiled with built in mod_deflade/GZIP support
# then GZIP Javascript, CSS, HTML and XML so they're sent to
# the client faster.
#
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript text/css text/html text/xml 
</IfModule>

# Note: You are able to choose a different name in the Admin CP. If you've done that you need to change it here too
<Files "error.log">
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
</Files>
```

here is htaccess from https://lofty-tibiabot.com/new/

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between `BEGIN WordPress` and `END WordPress` are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /new/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /new/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed your website address from database? Please try first with that.

Comment: yes i have changed addresses from db when i moved this website to this domain and folder. its from db: siteurl
https://lofty-tibiabot.com/new
home
https://lofty-tibiabot.com/new